# Finding moment of 4 points

Tags: opencv

I have a 4 point that I want to calculate the moment on, but I am getting an error.

I am using the opencv moment call, like this.

Moments mom = moments( points, false );

these are the points I have.

points = [4]({x=119 y=376 },{x=126 y=436 },{x=66 y=443 },{x=59 y=383 })

Error I get:

Expression: (unsigned)CV_MAT_DEPTH(type) <= CV_64F

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using C++ or Python?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your source code to debug this error.

However the following should work (in C++):

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points(4);
cv::Moments mom;
points[0].x = 119;
points[0].y = 376;
points[1].x = 126;
points[1].y = 436;
points[2].x = 66;
points[2].y = 443;
points[3].x = 59;
points[3].y = 383;

mom = cv::moments(points, false);
```